# Formatting sql when using aliases

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, alias

I have this block of sql in a script:

```
update #Result
Set FacilityTotals = 'Facility Total: IS Needed Yes: ' + 
                     (select count(ISNeeded_YN) 
                      from #ISReview C, #Result R 
                      where CustomerID = C.CustomerID and ISNeeded_YN = 'Y') + 
                     ' No: ' + 
                     (select count(ISNeeded_YN) 
                      from #ISReview C 
                      where CustomerID = C.CustomerID and ISNeeded_YN = 'N') + 
                      ' IS Yes: ' + 
                     (select count(IS_YN) 
                      from #Result C 
                      where CustomerID = C.CustomerID and IS_YN = 'Y') + 
                     ' No: ' + 
                     (select count(IS_YN) 
                      from #Result C 
                      where CustomerID = C.CustomerID and IS_YN = 'N')
```

When I try to run it, I get the following errors:

> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 500
>   Ambiguous column name 'CustomerID'.
>   Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 500
>   Ambiguous column name 'ISNeeded_YN'.
>   Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 500
>   Ambiguous column name 'ISNeeded_YN'.

`ISNeeded_YN` is in the `#isReviewTable`, while `CustomerID` is in both tables. I'm pretty new to this type of sql, how do I write this correctly?

Comment: Beyond the current problem, you have a more insidious one - due to the fact of your implicit join in your first sub-query, the totals you're getting are most likely way off (as a multiple of however many rows are in `#result`).  Why are you updating a table like this?  I would have used a standard select statement, never mind the concatenated strings.

Answer (score 4):

You need to prefix your columns with the table name.

For example,

This piece.

```
CustomerID = C.CustomerID
```

It knows that the right side is from #IsReview, but it has no idea which table to use for left side.  It might be obvious to you but sql only knows that you have that column on multiple tables and it doesn't know what to do.

`R.CustomerID = C.CustomerID` would resolve the issue for you in that particular location.

You just need to do that where ever you are referencing your columns that are used in more than one table.